# Links in sr-only disturbs focus order for keyboard users with vision

Tags: html, svg, bootstrap-4, accessibility

I am working on a float chart with multiple clickable links inside a SVG. The plan is to hide the SVG from screen readers using `<svg aria-hidden="true">` and have a description below the image `<div class="sr-only">` (bootstrap 4) containing a description and the same links. While the SVG is hidden from screen readers, and the information inside `.sr-only` is hidden from users with vision, the links inside `.sr-only` is giving focus to the hidden links. Users with vision vil experience wrong focus order because of the hidden links.

Is there a common solution to this? Are `.sr-only` for text only and no links?

Comment: You will probably need `<svg focusable="false">` as well.

Comment: In that way users with vision won't be able to navigate the links using keyboard. And they can not navigate focusable but invisible links inside .sr-only. WCAG 2.1.1 https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/keyboard.html

Comment: If you are hiding the `<svg>` from screen reader users with `aria-hidden` then you need to remove keyboard focus as well using `focusable="false"`. That does not create a 2.1.1 issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons that you have well experienced yourself, it's indeed a bad idea to put links or any other focusable element inside a zone with .sr_only or aria-hidden=true.

If you do it, in both case you are putting people into troubles:

- People having vision won't see the focus going to a hidden zone with .sr_only. Or maybe they will see it because the browser will detect that it's off-screen and pout some kind of visual artifact to make it visible as long as the focus is there, but it will still anyway look strange.
- Screen reader have a problem when an element inside aria-hidden=true takes the focus. The focused element won't be announced at all, or will be announced but will stay absent from the virtual buffer, which is inconvenient in both cases.

So, both .sr_only and aria-hidden=true are to be reserved to rather short non-interactive indications that are useful for particular users, while useless for other.

As a reminder, .sr_only and aria-hidden=true aren't exactly opposite of eachother. Content under .sr_only is hidden from the screen and readable by screen readers, while aria-hidden=true hides the content from screen readers **and all other assistive tools**.
Don't forget about screen magnifiers, eye trackers, vocal control, highlighters for dys-troubles, etc.

Comment: I agree with QuentinC, don't put interactive elements inside an `sr-only`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I will have to make the SVG work for screen readers. I will have to make sure both links and link description inside the SVG is  read by most screen readers (and focusable). And have text explanation only inside .sr-only.

Comment: Do make your SVG accessible! It's always better than simply discard it with aria-hidden=true even if you don't make a perfect job. Additional .sr_only description is still always welcome to describe things that users can't see. Keep in mind that, as explained, aria-hidden=true potentially prevent all assistive tools from accessing the image and not only screen readers, so users of eye trackers and voice control won't be able to activate elements that they perfectly see.